# Python round() error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

What is wrong with the `round` function in Python 3.6.3? I tested the code below:

```
a = 0.5
b = 0.5000001
print (round(a),round(b))
```

..and get result as

```
0 1
```

So rounding `0.5` -> `0` but `0.500001` -> `1`. Should both variables get value of `1`?

Comment: I would expect the output you received... See [bankers rounding](http://wiki.c2.com/?BankersRounding)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) Python 3.x rounds half to even by default.

Comment: Yes they should and it does in 2.7 and 3 as well, idk why it's not working right quiet strange , but whatever , i have seen stranger things!

Comment: @UbdusSamad: you may want to read the answer to the duplicate (and links therein) for the reasoning behind this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's described in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

> If ndigits is omitted or is None, it returns the nearest integer to
>   its input.
>
> For the built-in types supporting round(), values are rounded to the
>   closest multiple of 10 to the power minus ndigits; if two multiples
>   are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice (so, for
>   example, both round(0.5) and round(-0.5) are 0, and round(1.5) is 2).

Answer (score -1):

**Both variable will not get value 1.**
because the value between range from 0.0000000 to 0.5000000  will round off to 0 ,but **when you increase any decimal bit after 0.5 it will round off to 1.**